# How do I display an image in a web form in asp.net Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, visual-studio

I have created an image folder in my root project folder

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/" />
```

I am linking my images here:

```
        if (dropDownList.SelectedItem.Value == "Picture 1")
        {
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/picture1.jpg"
        }
```

When I visit the web page I get a small img box with an x instead of my image.

Comment: @Dwilight Right click that x image and click "Open image in new tab" and see if the url is valid? Also, the line of code is not valid Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/picture1. and it is missing image extension and closing quote.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood that was just a typo. I have the extension and the quote in the actual code. It won't let me select "Open Link in new tab" option it is grayed out. I am running this on Internet Explorer.

Comment: Try some other browser e.g. chrome. Also, code for setting the ImageUrl is conditional based on the drop down selected value so ensure that this code is executing.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood okay I tried it in Chrome and I selected open image in new tab and I got an error message stating "403.14 The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory." Also I'm not sure what you mean by ImageUrl being conditional based. How would I change that?

Comment: It means that your conditional code if (dropDownList.SelectedItem.Value == "Picture 1") is not working and the ImageUrl is set to "~/images/" not to "~/images/picture1.jpg"

Comment: What I'm trying to do is of the user selects second it in drop down list then Image1 will show a different picture. I only have one kmabe showing multiple pictures.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @Dwight can you paste your dropdownlist's html here ?

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/" />
```

is setting the url to a directory (folder), not an image. That's why you're getting the small image-box and not an image.

If you want an image to show up when the page loads, set it to a valid image:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/picture1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/" />
```

This line of code is setting an invalid image url as it only contains the folder path. So in your code you must ensure that you override the Image1's ImageUrl property to valid image file. Based on your requirement here is something you can do.

In aspx page, set the image url to picture1.jpg assuming that option1 is selected by default in the dropdown so picture1.jpg will be displayed on initial page load.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/picture1.jpg" />
```

Next, set the AutoPostBack property of your dropdown to true so that image source code can be updated dynamically based on dropdown selected value

```
 <asp:DropDownList 
             ID="DropDownList1"
             runat="server"
             AutoPostBack="true"
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In selectedIndexChanged event handler update image source based on the selectedItem

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It was displaying the small image box with X as it was not able to find the image at the path specified.

So, Add you images folder in ***wwwroot*** folder instead of Project root.

After that you can use `<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/picture1.jpg" />`

for rest you can follow [Mohsin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474947/10287964) answer

Answer (score -1):

Try to use .Scr instead of ImageUrl.

Comment: <asp:Image> server side image has ImageUrl which set <img src property